# Google Sheets: Need conditional format formula to parse number-hyphen-number input into "2-Tuesday" type

Tags: conditional-formatting, google-sheets

I want to write a conditional formatting formula that will convert

`1-3` to `1-Thursday`,

`2-2` to `2-Wednesday`,

`3-1` to `3-Tuesday`,

`4-0` to `4-Monday`.

The rationalization being I have a list of committee meeting dates, which fall on ordered days of the week, not specific days. So I want a date type (as in "second Wednesday") that can be inputted and sorted numerically but read by the user as a string. I already know that the following formula will spit out a "Monday":

`=TEXT(WEEKDAY(0),'dddd')`

and that I can concatenate specific valued strings such as:
`=CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE("2,"-"),TEXT(WEEKDAY(0),"dddd"))`

to make "2-Monday".

So how can I pose a formula that will interpret a pattern in the form number-hyphen-number to this for arbitrary numeric values (assuming the 3rd character is a number 0-6)?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I have come up with does not use conditional formatting. Instead, it uses a column of hyphenated, single-digit numbers to fill another column.

**Test case**

Cell E5: 1-3

Cell F5: `=CONCATENATE(LEFT($E5,2),CHOOSE(RIGHT($E5,1),"MONDAY","TUESDAY","WEDNESDAY","THURSDAY","FRIDAY","SATURDAY","SUNDAY"))`

**RESULT:** `1-WEDNESDAY`

I have verified this will work for any digit 1...7 on the right-hand-side.
This indexing system was nudged from 0...6 to 1...7 because the CHOOSE function begins with 1, not 0.

A conditional format formula would still be preferable to this because then we would not need the extra column to do the conversion.